# Need help for gre questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Of the $240$ employees at a certain company, $75$ percent attended the company's $25$th anniversary receptions. Of the employees who attended the reception, $80$ percent brought one guest each and the rest each brought either no guests or $2$ guests. Which of the following could be the total number of company's employees and their guests who attended the reception?

A. $300$

B. $330$

C. $350$

D. $380$

E. $410$

F. $430$

I'm not sure whether my interpretation is wrong or the answer is wrong.

My approach as since we have $75$ percent of member attended the reception, then the total number who attended the reception is $75\% \times 240 = 180$.

Within $180$ members, there are at least $144$ guests since $80\%$ of $180$ members brought at least $1$ guest, and out of $36$ member brought either no guests or $2$ guests.

So the range of total members and guests who attended the reception is

$180+ 144 + 36 \times 0= 324$  to $80 + 144 + 36 \times 2 = 396$

The answer I have should be BCD, but the given answer is EF.

I probably missed something, any suggestions?

Comment: Your calculations look right to me. Is this the exact wording of the problem?

Comment: yes I believe so, highly chance that the answer is wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it appears as though you are correct and the problem must be mislabeled (or you've mis-transcribed something). Here is a formal algebraic solution:

#### Variables

$A = $ attendees

$E = $ employees

$E_A = $ employees in attendance

$G_A = $ guests in attendance

$f_{EA} = $ fraction of the total employees that are in attendance

$f_i = $ fraction of the employees in attendance that brought i guests, where $i \in [0,2]$

$g_i = $ guests per employee in attendance, where $i \in [0,2]$

#### Algebra

$A = \left[ E_A \right] + \left[ G_A \right]$

$A = \left[ E_A \right] + \bigl[ \left(f_0 \times E_A \times g_0\right) + \left(f_1 \times E_A \times g_1\right) + \left(f_2 \times E_A \times g_2\right) \bigr]$

factoring $E_A$ out of the expressions on the right and acknowledging that $g_0 = 0$, $g_1 = 1$, and $g_2 = 2$:

$A = E_A \bigl[ \left[ 1 \right] + \left(0\right) + \left(f_1\right) + \left(2 \times f_2 \right) \bigr]$

$A = E_A \bigl[ 1 + f_1 + 2 f_2 \bigr]$

Where $E_A = f_{EA} \times E$:

$A = f_{EA} \times E \times \bigl[ 1 + f_1 + 2 f_2 \bigr]$

Where $f_{EA} = 0.75$, $E = 240$, and $f_1 = 0.8$:

$A = 0.75 \times 240 \times \bigl[ 1 + 0.8 + 2 f_2 \bigr]$

$A = 180 \times \bigl[ 1.8 + 2 f_2 \bigr]$

Where $f_2 \in [0, 0.2]$

$A_{min} = 180 \times \bigl[ 1.8 + 2 \times 0 \bigr]$

$A_{min} = 180 \times \bigl[ 1.8 \bigr]$

$\therefore A_{min} = 324$

$A_{max} = 180 \times \bigl[ 1.8 + 2 \times 0.2 \bigr]$

$A_{max} = 180 \times \bigl[ 2.2 \bigr]$

$\therefore A_{max} = 396$

#### Final Note: Deceptive English

In theory, it is possible that more than 75% of the employees were in attendance. It would be outrageous for the GRE to be that deceptive, but, in theory, if 100% of the employees were in attendance, it would also be true that 75% of the employees were in attendance. It is pretty straightforward to show that, in that case, the maximum number of attendees would be 528. Even more ridiculously, it could be true that 80% of the employees in attendance brought more than one guest, but it would also be true that 80% of the employees brought one guest. If you are actually studying for the GRE, I highly recommend you disregard this entire paragraph, assume the correct answer was supposed to be BCD, and move on.